# Blank space under facebook-like button plugin

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm using the Facebook button plugin but it is dropping the content after the button too far down and creates empty space.

I tried to add a data-height value to the dev with no luck...any ideas?

Sample:  http://tinyurl.com/765znxp

Comment: If you mean it is pushing the image down, you have a <br> there, is that intentional?

Comment: No, just under the facebook like button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a br causing the issue directly below the facebook widget